# How to re-create the x-terminal-emulator alternative?

Tags: command-line, shortcut-keys, update-alternatives

I've just installed Ubuntu GNOME 16.04 and while trying to add `terminix` as the default terminal emulator I messed up really bad the `x-terminal-emulator` alternative, totally my fault!

I entered the `update-alternatives --install` command wrong and now I don't have that alternative anymore, this is what I got now:

```
$ sudo update-alternatives --config x-terminal-emulator
There is only one alternative in link group x-terminal-emulator (providing /usr/bin/x-terminal-emulator): /usr/bin/gnome-terminal.wrapper
Nothing to configure.
update-alternatives: warning: forcing reinstallation of alternative /usr/bin/gnome-terminal.wrapper because link group x-terminal-emulator is broken
update-alternatives: warning: not replacing /usr/bin/x-terminal-emulator with a link
```

Fortunately, the only problem is that I can't use the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> shortcut to open the terminal (or any terminal emulator for that matter). Invoking them with <kbd>Super</kbd> and searching using the name of the application works without any problem. Like I said, it's  not a big problem but it bothers me having it.

I've tried reinstalling the emulators but without any luck. If you know any possible solution to my dilemma I'll really appreciated!

Comment: The shortcut thing can be set via `gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.default-applications.terminal exec 'x-terminal-emulator'` (replace the `x-terminal-emulator` with whatever you want).  As for the alternatives, I'd suggest you try `--install` part again.  Alternatives system is nothing more than symlinks, so you could also do that manually , link `/etc/alternatives/x-terminal-emulator` to whatever terminal you want

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same problem. What fixed it for me was to simply re-install `gnome-terminal` i.e. typing the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall gnome-terminal
```

This seems to automatically reset the alternatives.

Comment: It doesn't work to me

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and I fixed it by reading the [`update-alternatives` man page](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/en/man1/update-alternatives.1.html).

According to that, `update-alternatives` has the following option:

```
--config <name>
    show alternatives for the <name> group and ask the user to select which one to use".
```

So run `sudo update-alternatives --config x-terminal-emulator`.
In my case it gave me the following output:

```
  Selection    Path                             Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
  0            /usr/bin/gnome-terminal.wrapper   40        auto mode
  1            /usr/bin/gnome-terminal.wrapper   40        manual mode
* 2            /usr/bin/guake                    1         manual mode

Press <enter> to keep the current choice[*], or type selection number:
```

I specified `0` and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> and got:

```
update-alternatives: using /usr/bin/gnome-terminal.wrapper to provide /usr/bin/x-terminal-emulator (x-terminal-emulator) in auto mode
```

Now the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> shortcut again opens the default terminal.

If you want to know more about the `auto mode` vs `manual mode` options shown in the output above, check [heemayl's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/288811) in [Difference between auto mode and manual mode in update-alternatives](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/288808/322816).

Answer (score 0):

I think, reconfiguring may help easily here:

```
$ sudo  dpkg-reconfigure your_terminal_program
```

Comment: It doesn't work to me

Comment: @HosseinKurd then ask new question and provide as much info as you can