# Deepin-terminal not showing up in x-terminal-emulator list

Tags: update-alternatives

Following [this post](https://askubuntu.com/a/578313/883501) I tried this command:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config x-terminal-emulator
```

But it doesn't list the deepin-terminal:

```
There are 2 choices for the alternative x-terminal-emulator (providing /usr/bin/
x-terminal-emulator).

  Selection    Path                             Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
  0            /usr/bin/terminator               50        auto mode
* 1            /usr/bin/gnome-terminal.wrapper   40        manual mode
  2            /usr/bin/terminator               50        manual mode

Press <enter> to keep the current choice[*], or type selection number
```

I have also tried from [this other question](https://askubuntu.com/q/790868/883501), these two commands:

```
sudo apt install --reinstall deepin-terminal
sudo dpkg-reconfigure deepin-terminal
```

None worked, do you have any other ideas?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 9):

For me, the following worked

https://github.com/linuxdeepin/deepin-terminal/issues/186#issuecomment-517919007

```bash
# Register deepin terminal
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/x-terminal-emulator x-terminal-emulator /usr/bin/deepin-terminal 50

# Select your terminal
sudo update-alternatives --config x-terminal-emulator
```

No reboot needed. Tested on Ubuntu.

Comment: This worked for me on Ubuntu 20.04 TLS running Gnome 3.36.1

Comment: This worked for me! Thanks.

Comment: This does not work for me.

Comment: @MarioPalumbo what did you get?

Comment: I always get the gnome terminal but I found the problem was in cinnamon's settings, in the "favorite applications" section. Once changed to "deepin terminal" the problem was solved.

Answer (score 1):

the only solution that I found was [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18647630/4661523):

```bsh
sudo gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.default-applications.terminal exec /usr/bin/deepin-terminal
sudo gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.default-applications.terminal exec-arg "-x"
```

And It works for me.

Comment: Thank you. I also had to logout and login for it to kick into effect.